# error message at page level for visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, error-messages, pagemessages

At page level , it's showing single error message but we have multiples error messages on multiple fields level.
How can show multiple error message at page level.

....

```
public PageReference saveDeals(){
        try{
                showPgMSG=true;
                upsert d;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
           // ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,e.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }
        if(d.Id==null){
            return null;
        }
        CommunityUtilityClass.DeleteListPageCookies('deal');
        return new PageReference(CommunityUtilityClass.getCommunityUrl('/apex/CommunityDealRegListView'));
    }



public PageReference GoPrevious(){
    PageReference page=null;
    if(clnbtn== true){
        page= new PageReference(CommunityUtilityClass.getCommunityUrl('/apex/CommunityAddDeals?id='+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')));
      page.setRedirect(true);
      return page;
    }
    if(navHistoryMgr.history.size()>0){
        page=new PageReference(navHistoryMgr.history[navHistoryMgr.history.size()-2].path);
    }
    else{
        page=new PageReference(CommunityUtilityClass.getCommunityUrl('/apex/communityDashboard'));
    }
    page.setRedirect(true);
    return page;
}
```

Comment: Are you generating all the errors via explicit code in your controller? If you are, you need to call ApexPages.addMessage for each condition that you want to report. The (commented out) code you show would only add one message for the first error assuming you flag the error by throwing an exception. Please explain more about your code and page in your question if I've mis-understood what you are doing.

Comment: I want to show error message at page level for each error message. At field level getting error message for each field.

Comment: <apex:pageMessages id="pgmsg" rendered="{!showPgMSG}"/>
           
                <div class="grid__item one-half palm--one-whole lap--one-whole">
                 
                 
                  <fieldset>
                    <legend>{!partnerInformationLabel}</legend>
                    <div class="field full-width">
                        <label for="">{!CompanyNamelbl}

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow: the normal (nice and simple) method is to add the messages in the controller and just use the [apex:pageMessages](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm) to present nicely styled output.